# Call PostgreSQL function from Java JDBC driver

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, jdbc, jdbc-postgres

I call a procedure in the following way:

```
CallableStatement delete_procedure = connection.prepareCall("{ call schema.delete( ? ) }");

delete_procedure.setInt(1, id);
delete_procedure.execute();
delete_procedure.close();

connection.close();
```

When I run the command `delete_procedure.execute()`, the program crashes. I do not experience any exceptions. What is causing this behavior? I am using the following function, which works fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.delete(integer)
    RETURNS void AS
alter table schema.table disable trigger del_trg;
delete from schema.table where id = $1;
alter table schema.table enable trigger del_trg;
```

Comment: Use a regular `PreparedStatement` and use `select schema.delete(?)` as the SQL query. `CallableStatement` is intended for procedures, not functions.

Comment: Are you saying that the program crashes without a stack trace or message of any kind?

Comment: I have same result with PreparedStatement!!

Comment: Joni: without a stack trace or message!